# I have a list of checkboxes and a submit button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I like to enable the cancel button if minimum one job is checked.

#### This is my HTML View

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in jobs" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
     <td style="width: 247px;">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
     </td>
     <td style="width: 247px;">{{ x.Name }}</td>
     <td style="width: 247px;">{{ x.Id }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<button ng-click="myFunc()" ng-disabled="countChecked()!=1">Cancel</button>
```

#### This is my script

```
$scope.countChecked = function(){
   var count = 0;
   angular.forEach($scope.jobs, function(){
     if (checked) count++;
   });

   return count;
 }
```

Iam new to AngularJS.

Answer (score 2):

Add `check` property inside each `job` of `jobs` collection.

```
<table >
     <tr ng-repeat="x in jobs" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
        <td style="width: 247px; ">
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.checked">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 247px; ">{{ x.Name }}</td>
        <td style="width: 247px; ">{{ x.Id }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then loop over each collection item and increament count by checking `checked` property of each `job`

```
$scope.countChecked = function(){
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.jobs, function(job){
        if (job.checked) count++;
    });

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a watch to the collection.

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in jobs" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
     <td style="width: 247px;">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
     </td>
     <td style="width: 247px;">{{ x.Name }}</td>
     <td style="width: 247px;">{{ x.Id }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<button ng-click="myFunc()" ng-disabled="!isAtLeastARowChecked">Cancel</button>


$scope.$watchCollection("jobs", function(newVal, oldVal){
    isAtLeastARowChecked = (newVal && newVal.length > 0);
});
```

I think it's a more readable, concise and elegant solution. For more info have a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).